# Write Brackets Inside Javascript Replace

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

```
function myFunction() {
  var text = document.getElementById("ansiText").value; 
  var finalText = text.replace(/)/g, "right");
 
  document.getElementById("ansiText").value = finalText;
}
```

I want to find and replace `(` as `left` and `)` as `right`.
But its didn't work if i write ) in code, its create errors. How can I write ( in replace function?

Comment: "its create errors" please always provide relevant errors

Comment: just escape the brackets: `text.replace(/\)/g, "right")` (I am too laze to search duplicates links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just escape the brackets to fix this: `text.replace(/\)/g, "right")`

```
function myFunction() {
  var text = document.getElementById("ansiText").value; 
  var finalText = text.replace(/\)/g, "right");
 
  document.getElementById("ansiText").value = finalText;
}
```